# How to make a Bootable USB?

Tags: live-usb

How do I make a bootable USB from Ubuntu? I've been looking online but end up confused. I see Startup Disk Creator but they way its worded it makes me think its only for making another Ubuntu USB.
I'm not very good with Linux. I only have it because I broke Windows. XD

If not clear, I broke Windows and had to install Linux. I am now wanting to know how to make a bootable USB from Linux. I already have the .iso file.

Comment: I should really proof read more often. Sorry about that.

Comment: Don't double post http://askubuntu.com/questions/734753/how-to-make-a-bootable-usb-in-ubuntu It is against the rules -1 to both questions

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with Windows only no problems. Refer to this [link](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/). You can make use of Universal USB installer and create a bootable USB for your favorite Ubuntu version

If you are trying to create Windows bootable USB  - you should refer to this [link](http://microsoft-news.com/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-drive-for-windows-10/) . It's for Windows 10 but you can find out the appropriate one for your Windows version.

Comment: I already have a bootable Ubuntu USB. I'm trying to make a bootable Windows USB. I broke Windows and had to install Linux on my laptop so now I'm trying to get back to Windows. Linux is to complicated for my simple mind. Plus I'm a gamer and most games come for Windows.

Comment: I have Linux currently installed. I'm not very good with it and as far as I know you can't run .exe. I'm using Linux to make a Bootable Windows USB. I already have a Ubuntu USB.

Comment: So you have to create the bootable USB in Linux, unless you can get a friend to loan you a Windows computer, or go to a library which has them. It would make things easier for you, then you could follow the steps on the website Ashu linked to, in his last paragraph.

Comment: If you have to do things from within Ubuntu, it might work simply to extract the files of the ISO to the root folder of your USB. That's all the procedure in "The hard way" chapter of the microsoft-news.com link suggests. You can do that with 7zip, which is available for Ubuntu. Make sure the USB is fat32 formatted.

Comment: @MagmaDude. if you are doing any such thing - I will recommend do it from Windows only.