# How to make a bootable USB IN Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-8, live-usb

How do you make a bootable USB INSIDE Ubuntu. My PC broke and I had to install Ubuntu to fix it. Now I need to make a bootable USB of Windows as I have the .iso file. So how do I make a bootable USB INSIDE Ubuntu. I've tried many methods and most have failed. I've even tried WinUSB but it won't download. Please help. I'm sure this has taken quite a few years from my life from stress.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Bootable USB?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/734729/how-to-make-a-bootable-usb)

Answer (score 0):

There is a great program that can be installed called `USB Creator`.

To install the application into Ubuntu, first press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal window.  Type in the following to install `USB Creator`:

```
sudo apt-get install usb-creator-gtk
```

After it is installed, I recommend that you launch the application with elevated permissions so that it can access the USB drive to help you create the bootable USB you're after.  The elevated access is used for formatting the USB drive as need be.

```
sudo usb-creator-gtk
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: After many stressfull hours I got it to boot on a CD. Now I have the trouble of I can't resize the pation. :(

Comment: Boot off the Ubuntu LiveUSB or CD, whatever version it was that you installed Ubuntu from.  There you can run a program called `gparted` that will allow you to resize your partition(s) to give you room to install your Windows.

Comment: I have that program but I'm having troubles resizing it. Do I need to unmount? As in it won't let me change that size, when I try to change the numbers they change back. I can't even use the slider.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be unmounted before it can be resized

Comment: "Could not unmount target is busy"

Comment: You need to run it from booted to the USB.

Comment: what? And what happens if when I get to Windows install I just delete it and install over it?

Comment: Not from the Windows disk.  What did you use to install Ubuntu?  Boot to that.  It is also a Live environment that allows you to use the computer.

Comment: Or you can delete it and install over it if that is what you want.

Comment: So I have Ubuntu install as techincally the primary OS. So you want me to use the Live Version and install again? I'm bad with Linux.

Comment: You might be looking at something here that is very complicated.  It is easier to install Windows first, then install Ubuntu after, as Ubuntu will resize and install bootloaders as needed.  Windows does not, so it is much more complicated.

Comment: The only way to install Windows would to to format the partion and install over Ubuntu. I'm fine with that I just don't want to break my PC again.

Comment: Then go ahead and do it that way.  It is not the only way, but it is indeed the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Like when I open Windows I'll have to delete the partion to make it unallocated and Windows will install over it. What happens then? Will my PC break because of no OS?